# How do I run Snap! without an internet connection?

Tags: local

I can run Snap! by visiting the website http://snap.berkeley.edu/snapsource/snap.html, but is there a way for me to run it when I don't have an internet connection?

Answer (score 7):

Snap! can be downloaded and run locally. When run locally, an internet connection is not necessary. This may be useful for students with a computer at home, but no reliable internet. Below are the instructions to download and run it.

1. Run Snap! from http://snap.berkeley.edu/snapsource/snap.html#
2. Click on the Snap! logo in the upper-left of the app.
3. Choose “Download source” from the menu
4. Save snap.zip locally on your computer.
5. Extract snap.zip.
6. Open snap.html in a web browser.

Every time you wish to run snap, you can do so by opening snap.html. No internet required.

[image]

---

Note that you cannot use cloud storage when running Snap! locally from snap.html. Also, the browser storage is not shared between running locally and running from the Berkeley website.

To transfer projects from a locally-run (offline) Snap! to the Berkeley-hosted (online) Snap!, you'll need to export the project from the locally-run Snap! window and import it in the Berkeley-hosted Snap! window.

Comment: The latest greatest code can also be downloaded from github: https://github.com/jmoenig/Snap--Build-Your-Own-Blocks

Comment: @jcmack: Nice! I'll have to take a look.